# Password Encryption change for windows ASP configuration

Tags: asp.net, oledb, password-encryption

My application using windows server (ASP) and connecting to another app "B" database by OLEDB (Connection string). App "B" enabled password encryption on their DB and no app is unable to connect their database.

SO i need a help to add the "CS_SEC_ENCRYPTION = CS_TRUE". Please let me know where and how to add this?

If i need to add this in web.config, then how i can add that?

if any other option, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Based on below link, add `;EncryptPassword=1;` in your `connectionString`, that is available in your web.config file.

http://sybperl-l.peppler.narkive.com/cd3C6AAS/does-dbd-sybase-support-cs-sec-encryption

Give a try and put a comment, so that I can delete if not working.

Comment: I have a connection string used in code as below                     
ConnectString ="Data Source="&getServerNameAndPort("sample_variable")&";User ID=******;Pwd=******;"                                                                                     Please help here where to add ;EncryptPassword=1; ?

Comment: Thank you so much. This is worked. I have added ** EncryptPassword=1** at the end and it worked.